# SQL query - Select multiple results as a column field

Tags: sql, join, select

I have table called **main**:

```
  t_pdno              t_mitm
SFC093989   SLS005251ACL-3382012763-1
SFC093991   SLS005251ACL-3382012765-1
SFC093996   SLS005251ACL-3382014708-1
SFC093993   SLS005251ACL-3382014709-1
```

I have another table called **brach**:

```
          t_mitm           t_opno
SLS005251ACL-3382012763-1   10
SLS005251ACL-3382012763-1   20
SLS005251ACL-3382012763-1   30
SLS005251ACL-3382012763-1   40
SLS005251ACL-3382014708-1   50
SLS005251ACL-3382014708-1   80
SLS005251ACL-3382014708-1   30
SLS005251ACL-3382014708-1   40
```

You can see the repeating field is **t_mitm**. **Main.t_mitm** is unique. But for every **t_mitm** there are multiple rows in **branch** table.

Is it possible to select all rows from **main** and to display additional column called Options where to present all the **t_opno** for every **t_mitm** record. In other words the final result based on provided data should be:

```
  t_pdno              t_mitm            Options
SFC093989   SLS005251ACL-3382012763-1   10,20,30,40
SFC093991   SLS005251ACL-3382012765-1    
SFC093996   SLS005251ACL-3382014708-1   50,80,30,40
SFC093993   SLS005251ACL-3382014709-1
```

I made a SQL-fiddle:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dd5661

Comment: Just a tip, make it easy to assist you. Sample data like A, B, C etc are much easier to read than SLS005351ACL-3382012763-1, SLS005251ACL-3382017763-1, SLS006251ACL-3382014763-1 etc.

Comment: You have tagged the Mysql and your fiddle is SQLServer ? Please tell us what database do you use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the database is MS SQLServer then this is the query you need:

```
select a.t_pdno, a.t_mitm, STRING_AGG (b.t_opno, ',')
from main a 
left join branch b on a.t_mitm =b.t_mitm
group by a.t_pdno, a.t_mitm
```

You need to use left join to get all the options from the first table even if they do not have a matching data in the second table.

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dd5661/9)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use join and group concat

```
Select a.t_pdno, a.t_mitm, group_concat(b.t_opno)
from main a inner join branch b on a.t_mitm =b.t_mitm
group by a.t_mitm
```

Please correct any typo if present as I am using my mobile